# Should I store UK postcode data in my database

Tags: api

I am building a website for a UK audience that will utilise location data to offer search results based on a desired location or home address.

I have a large list of UK postcodes and geographic locations that I could parse and input to my DB to use in searches

I am wondering if this is the right thing to do?

Would it be better to just rely on an API such as google geolocation?

Comment: How often does this data change (zipcodes in the US change rarely, but they do change)?  Will you want to be able to query it as the zipcode ("how many people from zipcode 12345?")?  Is there additional information in the zipcode that you will want?

Comment: There is an update from the source roughly every 3 months. Changes are minimal, the zipcode data will mainly be used to determine point of origin

Comment: Would the geolocation datatypes in postgres be of some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does the API work? Do you make a call to the API, and the API looks up the data on Google's servers? The risk there, of course, is that if anything happens to your service provider (Google), you won't be able to do the lookup. Since you have lookup data that you can use locally, I'd recommend using it. It makes you less dependent on third-party APIs and will probably be faster (in theory, anyway) since there's no calls to outside systems. How much data is it? A few thousand rows? Most databases can handle that with no problem if you index it properly. You could even have it loaded to an in-memory cache when your application starts, so you don't even have to go to the database to retrieve it.

Comment: Its a couple of million+ rows to store locally, I thought in some circumstances(where necessary) I would get more detail from google and then store locally so as not to have to repeat the call to google in future. Your answer is exactly my first instinct but I just want second opinions

Comment: Hmm ok that's more data than I thought... I'd still try a local solution first, and only move to using Google if the local solution just can't be made to work fast enough.

Comment: @allen213 couple million?  UK has a population of about 62M. There are only [41810 zipcodes in the US](http://www.zip-codes.com/zip-code-statistics.asp).

Comment: @MichaelT - There are 1.78 million - http://cdu.mimas.ac.uk/pclut/

Comment: Our streets are small

Comment: @ChrisF it appears that the US 5 digit zipcode would map approximately to the district or sector in the UK.  The US 5 digit zipcode encodes the central mail processing center with the first three digits, and then the post office with the last two digits.  We've started getting a "zip+4" format which encodes approximately a city block (similar to the 1.78M number).

Comment: UK postcodes typically identify a group of about 10 or so addresses (some special postcodes are used by only one) - in fact, you can address a letter with only the house number and postcode and it will be delivered